# Get Group Permissions from LDAP with C# (READ ACL)

Tags: c#, permissions, active-directory, ldap

I like to get the permissions from a group. 
e.g. User in this Group can Read, or Write...

I work with Microsoft ActiveDirectory.

With the DirectorySearcher I search like this:

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootDSE)
{
    Filter = searchString,
    //SecurityMasks = SecurityMasks.Dacl | SecurityMasks.Owner | SecurityMasks.Group | SecurityMasks.Sacl
    SecurityMasks = SecurityMasks.Dacl | SecurityMasks.Group
    //SecurityMasks = SecurityMasks.Dacl
    //SecurityMasks = SecurityMasks.Group
            };
```

the ntSecurityDescriptor is a byte array in my Code

```
group["ntSecurityDescriptor"][0] as byte[]
```

so far so good

and now I will try to list the permissions:

```
static void ReadAccess(byte[] sec)
{
    System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity retVal = new System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity();
    retVal.SetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm(sec);

    //AuthorizationRuleCollection arc = retVal.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
    AuthorizationRuleCollection arc = retVal.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
    //AuthorizationRule || ActiveDirectoryAccessRule
    foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule acr in arc)
    {
        string sid = null;
        try
        {
            sid = (acr.IdentityReference).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
        }
        catch { }

        bool all = acr.ActiveDirectoryRights == ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericAll;
        bool read = acr.ActiveDirectoryRights == ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericRead;
        bool write = acr.ActiveDirectoryRights == ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericWrite;
        bool execute = acr.ActiveDirectoryRights == ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericExecute;
        bool extended = acr.ActiveDirectoryRights == ActiveDirectoryRights.ExtendedRight;

        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", all, read, write, execute, extended);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", acr.ActiveDirectoryRights, acr.AccessControlType, sid);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

dont understand the result
[image: wrong way]

I think I´m on the wrong way
=> I hope anyone can help me

Comment: What part do you not understand? I can help explain, but I don't know what part to explain :)

Comment: thank you. It's a basic communication problem. I want to find out what rights the group "ADM_Group" has on group "Group". The goal is to find out if the user "XY" which is in the "ADM_Group" is allowed to add users to the "Group" or not, and the other direction with which group "Group" can edited. Probably my approach is not right, because I can only filter folder permissions here!?

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding correctly, you are seeing permissions for "ADM_Group" on your group, but you don't see that permission when you look at the permissions in your code.

You are excluding inherited permissions by passing `false` in the second parameter of [`GetAccessRules()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.directoryobjectsecurity.getaccessrules):

```
retVal.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier))
```

So if it is an inherited permission that is giving "ADM_Group" the permissions, then maybe that is why you are not seeing it.

In AD Users and Computers, you can click on 'Advanced' (or in your case 'Erweitert') to see each individual ACL in the permissions. The view in your screenshot combines ACLs to provide a simplified view of the permissions.

Comment: is it possible to see which access rights the group "ADM_Group" has in "Group"? e.g. Can he change Users...